# Make string comma delimited in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, delimiter

I have a string:

```
var myStr = 'This is a test';
```

I would like to make it comma delimited via JavaScript, like so:

```
var myNewStr = 'This, is, a, test';
```

What is the best way to accomplish this via JavaScript?

I know I can trim the commas like so:

```
var myStr = myNewStr.split(',');
```

And that would give me this:

```
myStr = 'This is a test';
```

But I am wanting to do the opposite of course, by adding commas.

Comment: what if there is a trailing space at the end of the string like `'This is a test '`, should it become `'This, is, a, test, '` ?

Comment: @Roman Guess no, should be trimmed.

Comment: Are you sure it is delimited by spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just replace with regex - it is shorter and no need to split.

```
var myNewStr = myStr.replace(/ /g,', ');
```

In case you could also face the string with leading / trailing spaces, just trim it beforehand.

```
var myNewStr = myStr.trim().replace(/ /g,', ');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this - `var myNewStr = myStr.split(' ').join(', ')`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression with a positive lookahead and replace then with a comma.

```js
console.log('This is a test'.replace(/(?= .)/g, ','));
console.log('This is a test '.replace(/(?= .)/g, ','));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.replace`:

```
var myStr = 'This is a test';
var myNewStr=myStr.replace(/ /g,', ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the replace function to replace the spaces with commas:

var myStr = myNewStr.replace(' ', ',');

You could also use:

var myStr = myNewStr.split(' ');

Comment: The first will only replace the first space with comma and won't go further, the second returns an array, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it without using the standard methods.

```js
var myStr = "THIS IS A TEST";
before.innerHTML = myStr;
var parts = [];
var buffer = '';
for(var i = 0; i < myStr.length; i++) {
    if(myStr[i] == ' ') {
        parts.push(buffer);
        buffer = '';
        continue;
    } else {
        buffer += myStr[i];
    }
}

parts.push(buffer)
var myNewStr = parts.join(', ');

after.innerHTML = myNewStr;
```

```html
<div><b>Before</b></div>
<div id="before"></div>
<div><b>After</b></div>
<div id="after"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `String.trim` and `String.replace` functions:

```
var myStr = ' This is a test ',
    myNewStr = myStr.trim().replace(/([^\s]+\b)(?!$)/g, "$&,");
    // $& - Inserts the matched substring.      

console.log(myNewStr);  // "This, is, a, test"
```